# TFS: How to merge only changes on my shelve, without overwriting local copy enterily

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to find a way to merge shelve changes with the latest version I have locally without overwriting my local files with those of the shelve.

That is, I have a shelve from date 0, on date 1 some changes were done in the tree, on date 2 I do a Get Latest Version, then when applying the shelve, changes of date 1 get lost.

No merge conflict between changes in date 1 and those of my shelve.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, what I ended up doing was to

1) "get specific version" to the date when changeset was taken

2) "get latest version".

That way, TFS merges latest version with changed local files. (The other way around -what I was looking for- seems not possible).

Answer (score 3):

Two options spring to mind:

*(Advice: Before you start, back up your code, in case there is anything in there that isn't safely stored on the server or in a shelve set!)*

- If you unshelve first, you will end up with locks on the shelved (0) files.
  Then GLV to get the (1) files. All the files you have locked will be merge conflicts, which you can then resolve, test, and check in as normal.
- Get the shelved code and copy it to another folder on your hard drive. Then GLV the latest server code. Check out the files you have changed (or easier, the root folder), and then manually merge the two sets of sources. You can then "undo check out" to get rid of the unchanged files (say "no" to the "discard your changes" question and it'll keep locks only on changed files) and after testing that your code works, check in the resulting changed files.

Answer (score 0):

You need another Workspace, that is a local folder were your working copy resides (Yes, you can have more than one).

With a fresh Workspace with no changes on it, you could recover your shelve there, do the check-in, and have your original workspace untouched. Optionally, you could delete the alternative Workspace, or keep it for these kind of maintenance tasks.

For creating a new Workspace, just open the Source Control Explorer and open the Workspace combo-box on the upper toolbar. Select Manage Workspaces and create a new one from there.